Shortest path to connecting all vertices of triangle
Given a triangle $\Delta ABC$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$, what is the shortest path connecting $A$, $B$, and $C$ provided the path can pass through anywhere on the plane?
Is it guaranteed that such a path with minimal length will be comprised of edges $AP$, $BP$ and $CP$ where $P$ is the Fermat point, instead of simply taking two of the edges of the triangle whose sum of lengths is minimal? Is this true for every triangle in general?

Yes, it's true in general. Be aware that the Fermat point is a vertex, if the angle is 120° or more.
